# Symfony form how to add class to form group

Tags: forms, symfony

Using:

```
->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'myclass'
                ],
            ])
```

I'm adding the class "myclass" to the `<input>` element, getting:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label ...>Name</label>
  <input type="text" required="required" class="myclass" ...>
</div>
```

What if I wanted to add the "myclass" class not to the input itself, but to its `<div class="form-group">` container, in order to get:

```
<div class="form-group myclass">
  <label ...>Name</label>
  <input type="text" required="required" ...>
</div>
```

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: You need to [override the used template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming). No way of doing that on the *php side*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I needed to override the **form_row** block:

```
{% block form_row -%}
    <div class="form-group myclass{% if (not compound or force_error|default(false)) and not valid %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

as suggested, the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) helps to understand why.

Answer (score 13):

I actually found a way of doing it in PHP (Symfony 4.4.2). Class has to go into 'row_attr' instead of 'attr'. For the given example it'd be:

```
->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name',
                'required' => true,
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'myclass'
                ],
            ])
```

related docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#row-attr

Answer (score 2):

As @Yoshi pointed out, in the form definition itself you **cannot** add classes to the container `div`.

The right way to customize form rendering is to override the base block via Twig as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field (BTW I suggest you to read carefully the whole article to know everything you need to know about customizations).

In the overridden block you have also the `widget` data if you want e.g. to add a class with the field id:

```
{% block _product_name_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget {{ id }}">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

in this example above, `{{ id }}` will be replaced with the widget (field) id.